# Bash swap String in file with different UUID's

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I'm having a custom xml and im trying to replace a multiple occurring string (say "uuidVariable") with a unique UUID each in Bash.

```
<dict>
    <key>Apple</key>
    <true/>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>uuidVariable</string>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>Banana</key>
    <false/>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>uuidVariable</string>
</dict>
```

I'm able to generate a UUID and store it :

```
UUID=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid)
```

But how is it possible to loop through myfile.xml and replace each string with a new UUID?

I know how to count the occurring string, but i don't think this is gonna help me further

```
countUUID=$(sed 's/uuidVariable/uuidVariable\n/g' myfile.xml | grep -c "uuidVariable")
```

EDIT:
Also i know how to replace 2 strings.. but thats not solving the problem having each unique.

```
sed -i s/uuidVariable/UUID/g myfile.xml
```

Comment: Likely answered by  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39350238/450611

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like this.

```
awk 'BEGIN { p="/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid" }
    /uuidVariable/ { getline uuid < p; close(p)
        sub("uuidVariable", uuid) } 1' file.xml >newfile.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Without external utilities, using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source=/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid

while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "${line//uuidVariable/$(<"$source")}"
done < input > output
```

---

Note that this solution **will be slow** for large input files. Some further reading:

- Parameter expansion: [wiki.bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
- Reading a file line-by-line: [mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)