# Getting lines formatted as CSV entries and perform conversions on them with sed

Tags: bash, sed, unix-timestamp, gnu-sed

When I try to grep something, I get:

```
09:00:02.052(0.0000<-0.0001<-0.0002)
15:04:07.225(75.8901<-78.1234<-79.4567)
16:08:11.463(100.0000<-100.0000<-100.0000)
```

values in () are percentage, so always lies in [0, 100]

So the input format will always be like:

```
HH:MM:SS.mmm(numbers1.xxxx<-numbers2.xxxx<-numbers3.xxxx)
```

And let's assume that the date is 20181025.

Is it possible to transform this grep result using awk/other unix command into a timeseries-like csv format:

```
unixtimestamp1,0.0000,0.0001,0.0002
unixtimestamp2,75.8901,78.1234,79.4567
unixtimestamp3,100.0000,100.0000,100.0000
```

- It is guaranteed that numbers are always with 4 digits.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but as per your expected output, can you try this and if this works?`sed 's#(#,#g ; s#<-#,#g ; s#)$##' file_name`....maybe there could be better ways to have the outcome..

Comment: What do you mean by `unixtimestamp1`? Do you want to assume that `09:00:02.052` is on today's date and then convert that date time into seconds since the unix epoche `1970-01-01`?

Comment: Hi Socowi, yes. The assumption is that 09:00:02.052 is on today's date and may need the unixtimestamp contains info of millisecond as well... ( 09:00:02.052 ). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this line:

```
sed 's/^\(.\+\).(\(.\+\)<-\(.\+\)<-\(.\+\)./printf "%.3f,%s,%s,%s" "$(date  --date="\1" +"%s.%N")" \2 \3 \4/e'
```

Output got:

```
1540537202.050,0.0000,0.0001,0.0002
1540559047.220,75.8901,78.1234,79.4567
1540562891.460,100.0000,100.0000,100.0000
```

Note : I assumed your localization (`LC_ALL`) formats floats with a dot, not a comma. Otherwise, set this variable before the sed command:

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/^\(.\+\).(\(.\+\)<-\(.\+\)<-\(.\+\)./printf "%.3f,%s,%s,%s" "$(date  --date="\1" +"%s.%N")" \2 \3 \4/e'
```

To get a timestamp from a date time string, you can use the command date. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10990961/4375327) for more details.

To execute this command with the first captured group (the date), I used the sed `e` flag, inspired from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39350238/4375327). It allows sed to get the input of a shell command passed.

More info with `info sed` ('sed' scripts -> The "s" Command) :

> This command allows one to **pipe input from a shell command** into pattern space.  If a substitution was made, the command that is found in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its output.  A trailing newline is suppressed; results are undefined if the command to be executed contains a NUL character. **This is a GNU 'sed' extension.**

So it may not work outside the GNU collection.

Comment: Hi Amessihel, your answer is indeed brilliant and achieve my goals! thank you very much! But 1 small issue is that: 1540476491 is a unix timestamp with accuracy of "second". The original 09:00:02.052 contains info of "millisecond". Is it possible to achieve this as well? Thanks!