# Replace date in a parameter file with system date

Tags: shell, sed, aix

In my Unix AIX I need to replace the date in a parameter file with system date using a shell script that will run post session from PowerCenter.

I can use SED to replace a string variable but running into issue using date.

I have tried using commas instead of slashes as delimiters. The contents of the test file looks like this:

```
$$TESTFIELD=12/29/2016 14:57:51
```

The sed command I felt should work was:

```
sed -e "s,^\($$TESTFIELD=\).*,\1'date +"%D %T"'," testfile.txt > tmp.$$
```

After which I would move the `tmp.$$` to `testfile.txt` but the results threw the following error:

```
sed: 0602-404 Function s,^\(14680298TESTFIELD=\).*,\1'date +%D cannot be parsed.
```

Comment: note that you are using double quotes, so `sed -e "s..."` expands `$$TESTFIELD` to its value.

Comment: You may want to have a look to [How to change date format in sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34080390/1983854) also, to see how to execute an external command from within `sed`. Basically, you need to use the `-e` flag.

Comment: Maybe: `Now=$(date +"%D %T"); sed "s,=.*$,=$Now," testfile.txt >>tmp.$$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quotes or escape the `$` in the `sed` command. Otherwise the shell would expand `$TESTFIELD`. I recommend the first in this case:

```
sed -e 's,^\($$TESTFIELD=\).*,\1'\''date +"%D %T"'\'','
```

Your question is quite unclear. If you want to replace the datetime in the file by the current datetime, use:

```
sed -e 's,^\($$TESTFIELD=\).*,\1'"$(date +"%D %T")"','
```

Comment: That approach doesn't insert the current date/time but actually inserts dat+"%D %T":
$$TESTFIELD='date +"%D %T"'

Comment: Reading your question, it looks like you want that

Comment: I apologize, I need the result to be 01/18/2017 12:34:30 or whatever the current date time is.

Comment: The results are now:
$$TESTFIELD='01/18/17 12:36:50'
I tried to remove a couple of the quotes to remove the quotes in the results. I can probably do this in PowerCenter later if its not easy here.

Comment: Removed them. Actually that was pretty simply

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's,^\($$TESTFIELD=\).*,\1'"$(date +"%D %T")"','
```

This worked perfectly. Results:
$$TESTFIELD=01/18/17 13:14:59